# Xamarin with vs : resource.Id does not contain a definition for ...

Tags: android, xamarin, media

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Media;

namespace Moosic
{
    [Activity(Label = "Moosic", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon1.png")]

    public class MainActivity : Activity

    {
        MediaPlayer player;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.again);

            Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.playButton);
            button1.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                player.Start();
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Error   CS0117  'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'playButton'    Moosic  c:\users\Farorex\source\repos\Moosic\Moosic\MainActivity.cs 25  Active

Creating a simple mediaplayer, have tried to rebuild solution and clean solution but doesnt seem to work

Comment: Please show your Main layout file, and refer to [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68568/axml-c-resources-does-not-contains-a-definition-for).

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting that button's id?
A *common* mistake I have seen people do is to use **@id** instead of **@+id**

In your activity layout you should have:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/playButton"
...
/>
```

Otherwise, it won't be created in Resource.designer.cs

Comment: If @id, the error will be  `Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/playButton').`